# No object is found when executing unit-tests with Karma in Angular CLI app

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I've setup my project with Angular CLI. Also I've created my components via "ng g component NAME". This also automatically added a test-class to create my unit-tests (which is of course pretty neat).

The problem is that my tests fail hard even though I left them in the initial state. I wanted to test it out before actually writing any test. However, the test fails horribly. Not a single line is executed well.

```
> ng test

'app-some-selector' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-some-selector' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Or for example

```
The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found
```

The above error is thrown for every single object in the specific components. If using another component via its selector, the corresponding component can not be found, if using a service like http through dependency injection, the compiler states that there is no provider for it and so on.

My project runs just fine with `ng serve` btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create component via angular-cli, it create for you

```
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This first test try to create a component and if you add a dependancie, other component for exemple, it fall.

To past this test you need to update the way you'r creating the component in the test class in the `beforeEach` function:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ myComponent ],
      providers: [myService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Here if i add a service `myService` in my component test dependancy injection. Like this, you can past mock object as a `myService` more easily to test your component.